# Prevent properties from generating resources

Tags: forms, web, localization

How do i prevent certain properties from generating resources when running the IDE "Generate Local Resource" tool?

I have applied the  attribute to properties as well to the entire class, which is a custom server control but resources are still being generated?

I have a control that inherits WebControls.Label and I would like to prevent the Text property from generating resources...

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Text property was defined as overloads - changing the property definition from Overloads to Overrides yields the expected results (e.g. no resource generated for that property).